# Как сделать виджет невидимым для механизма событий? (Qt, C++)

Tags: c++, qt

Есть ли какой-то способ, механизм событий думал, что виджета нет? То есть события проходили под него, например если под ним есть другой виджет, чтобы все события мыши передавались нижестоящему виджету - как если бы верхний виджет был скрыт.

Кажется, `event->ignore();` - это то, что мне нужно, но у меня это работает, только внутри одного окна. Можно ли настолько игнорировать событие, чтобы его получали виджеты в другом окне многооконного приложения(если например два окна накладываются друг на друга, то щелчок по верхнему приводил бы к срабатыванию события на нижнем)?

Comment: Попробуйте выставить `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, false);` для Вашего виджета.

Comment: @ixSci Та же проблема, что и с `event->ignore()` - внутри одного окна всё работает, но если по разным окнам разнести, то у нижних окон событие не срабатывает.

Comment: Значит надо играться с оконными классами и смотреть что там как.

Comment: @ixSci, у Вас верный ответ, только надо вторым аргументом указать `true`, а не `false`. По умолчанию "событийная прозрачность" как раз `false`, т.е. отключена.

Comment: @alexis031182 а, да с этим я разобрался. Ошибку сразу заметил, но писать не стал.

Comment: @Nik, лучше напишите в виде ответа, чтобы закрыть вопрос.